# $a<x-c<b \Rightarrow |x-c|<\min \{|a|,|b|\}$. Is this true?

Tags: real-analysis

I was doing Exercise 4.2.2 (b) of Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis (2nd ed), which is:

> Exercise 4.2.2. For each stated limit, find the largest possible $\delta$-neighborhood that is a proper response to the given $\epsilon$ challenge.
> $\text { (b) } \lim _{x \rightarrow 4} \sqrt{x}=2, \text { where } \epsilon=1 \text {. }$

and checking my solutions on [this website](https://linearalgebras.com/understanding-analysis-exercise-4-2.html), I came across the implication
$$a<x-c<b \Rightarrow |x-c|<\min \{|a|,|b|\}$$
Specifically, the solution said:

> We would like $|\sqrt{x}-2|<1$, that is
> $$
> -1<\sqrt{x}-2<1 \Longrightarrow 1<\sqrt{x}<3
> $$
> Hence we need $1<x<9$, which also implies
> $$
> -3<x-4<5
> $$
> Therefore, we must have
> $$
> |x-4|<\min \{|-3|,|5|\}=3
> $$
> The largest possible $\delta$ is $3$.

But expanding this gives $1<x<7$, and originally we had $1<x<9$. How can this identity hold true if we end up with a smaller interval of possible $x$ values? Thanks.

Comment: If $a=2,b=3,$ then what?

Comment: You are misreading the proof. The proof says, “we need $-3<x-4<5.$” So they are saying if $|x-4|<\min(|-3|,5)$ then $-3<x-4<5.$ It is not stating the reverse is true. This is only true here because $a<0$ and $b>0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is confusing because limit proofs like this do things backwards, and it is possible to read it wrong.

Here, the proof is saying “we need” $1<x<9,$ which is equivalent to $-3<x-4<5.$

What they are saying is that *if* $|x-4|<\min(|-3|,5),$ *then* $-3<x-4<5.$ You are reading the implication in reverse, because the proof is “backward.”

This is common to limit proofs. In reality, the proof could just start:

> If $|x-4|<3,$ then $-3<x-4<3<5.$ Then …

But we prove it backwards to show how we *got* the value $3.$

Otherwise, the choice of $3$ looks like magic, and, especially when teaching limit proofs, it is important to make clear *how* we get various values of $\delta,$ given an $\epsilon.$

Answer (score 4):

This is not true in general: $x = 8$ serves as a counterexample to $-3 < x - 4 < 5 \implies |x - 4| < \min\{|-3|, |5|\}$. However, they are finding the largest value of $\delta$ such that $|x - 4| < \delta$ implies $-3 < x - 4 < 5$, and that value of $\delta$ happens to be $\min\{|-3|, |5|\}$.